# How can I r group individual bars in ggplot 2 - bar plot by color?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colorbar

I am trying to visualize gene ontology data from David. I was able to create a bar plot and have arranged my data in descending order. I would like to organize this further based on its Category/fill color (to maintain same descending order per category). Any pointers will be helpful.  PFA my R script below and the image that I have so far.

```
library(readr)
#import read CSV file
HDvC <- read_csv("G0_all_HDvscontrol.csv")
head(HDvC)

library(ggplot2)

myplot1 <- ggplot(HDvC, aes(x = reorder(Description, neglogFDR),
                            y = neglogFDR, fill = Category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip() + labs(y = "-log (q value)",
                      x = "GO Description",
                      title = "HD vs Control") + theme_gray()

theme(plot.title = element_text(
  hjust = 0.5, # center
  size = 12,
  color = "gray0",
  face = "bold" ) 
) 

myplot1
```

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Sure. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try facet?

Add to your ggplot code:

```
+ facet_wrap(.~Category)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This seems to make it a lot better.